# React get object inside another object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a simple json api and want to display some of objects fields with react.
The api has the following structure:

```
{"data" : [
  0: Object
    id: "1"
    type: "Item"
    attributes: Object
      title: "lorem impsum"
      body: "lorem ipsum"

  1: Object
    id: "2"
....
]}
```

And I'm trying to display attributes items(title, body)

The problem is that

this works fine and displays id

```
{items.map(item => 
  <div>{item.id}</div>
)}
```

BUT

If I try to use `{item.attributes.title}` I receive

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

So `item.attributes` is undefined.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure every item has the `attributes` field defined?

Comment: try `{item.attributes && item.attributes.title}` and check output

Comment: just noticed, some of the attributes fields have `null` value. `{item.attributes && item.attributes.title}`- this works. I think I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the most common error that occurs because you never know what object you are going to get from server, so it is always good way to check before accessing the data, so you can try

```
{item.attributes && item.attributes.title ? item.attributes.title : 'print something for missing title' }

 //item.attributes && item.attributes.title means if both the values are present in Object
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help you. I couldn't find an error in your program. So, I've created a working example to solve this.

```js
const data = {
  "data": [{
    id: "1",
    type: "Item",
    attributes: {
      title: "lorem impsum",
      body: "lorem ipsum",
    }
  }, {
    id: "1",
    type: "Item",
    attributes: {
      title: "lorem impsum",
      body: "lorem ipsum",
    }
  }, {
    id: "1",
    type: "Item",
    attributes: {
      title: "lorem impsum",
      body: "lorem ipsum",
    }
  }, {
    id: "1",
    type: "Item",
    attributes: {
      title: "lorem impsum",
      body: "lorem ipsum",
    }
  }]
}

class Sample extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return <div>
      {
        data.data.map((el) => {
          return <div>
            <h1>{el.id}</h1>
            <div>{el.attributes.title}</div>
            <div>{el.attributes.body}</div>
          </div>
        })
      }
      </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Sample/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```